# Best way to manage theme images

Tags: thumbnails, images

I am currently wondering what is the best way to let the user choose between a certain number of thumbnail size for the shortcodes I am building.

`add_image_size` function is the simplest way but adding 10 size of thumbnail to the theme will create a enormous number of unneeded thumbnails.

I really want to avoid this, is there any good way to do this?

Comment: Maybe just give an option to select image size in shortcode and on `save_post` hook your function to create the selected image size for the attachment. Unless you want to show the thumbnails while the user makes a choice.

Comment: Add function could I use to create the selected image size for the attachement?
Using `wp_get_attachment_image` with an array instead of a thumbnail size, how would wordpress manage the image in this case?